# How to know if there are child divs hidden by overflow: hidden in Angular6

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

Here is the problem I want to solve.

```
 <div class="row" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <app-car
      *ngFor="let car of cars; trackBy: trackByFunction"
      [car]="car"
    >
    </app-car>
 </div>

 <button> More <button>
```

I want to show the more button if there are cars hidden by the overflow:hidden property of the parent.

Comment: please add more description so i can help you

Comment: Why don't you enable the button if the cars array length exceeds a particular limit?

Comment: I set the parent div max-height(to show only one row of cars) and overflow:hidden property. So that if the screen width is enough to display all cars in one line, to show them otherwise to hide the overflow. The problem is that I want to show a "more" button if there are cars that are hidden by the overflow:hidden css property of the parent div (There will be on small screen computers). I'm using angular 6. @Alex

Comment: show more button is what doing.?

Comment: I think this is more css related query

Answer (score 1):

jquery;

```
$("div").each(function() {
  if($(this).parent().css('overflow') == 'hidden'){
    console.log("there is an overflow hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: You are changing your question and title :D my answer doesnt work now, i hope u can find your final question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewChild and ngIf in angular6 to achieve your situation

```
<div class="row" style="overflow:auto;height:50px" #container>
<app-car
  *ngFor="let car of cars; trackBy: trackByFunction"
  [car]="car">
</app-car>
 </div>

<button *ngIf="container.style.overflow === 'hidden'"> More <button>
```

and include below item in your ts file

```
 @ViewChild('container') private container: ElementRef;
```